# How to add an arrow to CSWP results

Tags: navigation, cswp

I used `CSWP` to show different document uploaded on the site. You can set a limit to show upto 50 items, but what if i want to see more?

Is it possible to add a navigation arrow to change pages? And show the next 50 items?

Can i do it with the `script editor`? Or there is an option in the webpart for such stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use the `Search Result Webpart` the same way as you are using the `Content Search Web Part` as this already got a paging property.

Just add the result web part and copy the same query that you use in your CSWP.

In the search result web part properties, select how many items you wish to show and enable "Show paging". You can hide the rest of the settings to make it look more like the CSWP.

Unmark everything under settings but:

- Show ranked results
- Show promoted results
- Show result count
- Show paging

[image]